# firefox browser detection in ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, browser-detection

I just face this problem when starting to use Ubuntu.
I wonder why 
Request.Browser.Browser.ToLower().IndexOf("firefox")  return true for firefox on windows
but false for firefox on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the return value of `Request.Browser.Browser.ToLower()` to see what Ubuntu has there. Most probably it's called `iceweasel` instead of `firefox` there.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use browser detection...try using something like jQuery's .support functions.

Check WhatIsMyUserAgent or some similar site for what Ubuntu's Firefox builds are actually sending.

I believe Firefox is supposed to be in the FF UA string on Ubuntu...but I know for a fact **Gecko** is in the string, as that's the rendering engine used.